# Trying to translate my answer from JS to Ruby for The Odin Project

Tags: javascript, ruby

I posted previously, but didn't show my work thus far.

**The original problem:**

Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

**Here's my answer in JS:**

```
var sum = 0
fib = function(numMax){
for(i=0,j=1,k=0; k<numMax;i=j,j=x,k++ ){
    x=i+j;
    console.log(x);
    if (x%2 === 0) {
        sum += x;
    }
}
}
fib(32)
console.log(sum);
```

And I'm trying to solve the same problem in Ruby. Below is what I've come up with so far, but I'm really struggling putting the pieces together here:

```
sum = 0
def fib (num_max)
sum.each do |x|
i = 0, j = 1, k = 0 
if k < num_max
    i = j
    j = x
    x = i+j
    puts x
    if x % 2 == 0
        sum += x
    end
  end
end
fib(32)
puts sum
```

Comment: Please do not use StackOverflow to ask every question you have for this same site (Odin Project). This is the fourth or fifth I have seen, and I think one or two were closed/deleted. It is good that you are _this time_ showing your work. Next time, _edit_ the first question you made to include new details or work. But make sure that the edit does not change the intended question (or add additional questions).

Comment: You have enough rep. You can view the chat rooms. I suggest looking at Ruby and JavaScript rooms. The Odin Project also has google hangouts or chat dedicated to studying and working through the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
starting_sequence_array = [1,2]

while (starting_sequence_array[-2] + starting_sequence_array[-1]) < 4000000
    starting_sequence_array << (starting_sequence_array[-2] +  starting_sequence_array[-1])
end

puts starting_sequence_array.select{|i| i.even?}.inject(:+)
```

Comment: I edited my origin answer with adding puts. That would be ruby equivalent of console.log().

Comment: Just some suggestions re: your original code. 

Your code misses one 'end'. Each 'def' should have an 'end'; each 'if' should have an 'end'; each 'do' should have an 'end' (where one uses 'do' explicitly instead of curly brackets).

When you put sum = 0 above 'def', you are making it out of scope, so it won't work. Use @ to make it class variable or use it within the method. Also with 'sum', you cannot iterate over it with 'each' because it is an integer.  To check for a number being even, you can use 'even?' method.