# One final translation from JS to Ruby for The Odin Project

Tags: javascript, ruby

**The original problem:**

The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

**Here's my answer in JS:**

```
function largestPrimeFactor(n){
var i=2;
while (i<=n){
if (n%i == 0){
    n/=i;    
}else{
    i++;
    }
  }
console.log(i);
}
var a = 600851475143; 
largestPrimeFactor(a)
```

I've spent a number of hours trying to figure out how to do this in Ruby and here's what I came up with, but I can't get it to work:

```
def largestPrimeFactor (n)
i  = 2
while i <= n
    if n % i == 0
        n /= i 
     i++
        puts i
    end
  end
end

a = 600851475143
puts largestPrimeFactor(a)
```

Comment: Without reading all of your code, I can tell you that there is no `++` operator in Ruby. You would have to do something like `i += 1`

Comment: A casual glance is enough to see the structure doesn't match up. You have no **else** in your Ruby code.

Comment: Please do not use StackOverflow to ask every question you have for this same site (Odin Project). This is the fourth or fifth I have seen, and I think one or two were closed/deleted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to translate my answer from JS to Ruby for The Odin Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520545/trying-to-translate-my-answer-from-js-to-ruby-for-the-odin-project)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your initial question, all that you were missing was an `else` and instead of using `i++` you should use `i += 1`.

```
def largestPrimeFactor (n)
  i  = 2
  while i <= n
    if n % i == 0
      n /= i 
    else
      i += 1
    end
  end
end
```

This code however isn't very "ruby-ish" so I'll offer a couple of implementations that I might use instead.

There is no need to calculate this as ruby already has a way of determining prime factors. Just require `prime` which is part of the ruby standard library.

```
require 'prime'

def largestPrimeFactor(n)
  primes, _ = n.prime_division.transpose
  primes.max
end 

largestPrimeFactor(13195) # => 29
largestPrimeFactor(600851475143) # => 6857
```

The only downside to this method (as well as your original JS code) is  that the doesn't use something called memoization so calling `largestPrimeFactor` with a rather large number multiple times might result in wasted computation. We can solve this by using a slightly more complex version of my solution:

```
require 'prime'

def largestPrimeFactor(number)
  @largest_prime_factor ||= {}.tap do |hash|
    hash.default_proc = proc do |_, key|
      hash[key] = begin
        primes, _ = n.prime_division.transpose
        primes.max
      end
    end
  end[number]
end

largestPrimeFactor(13195) # => 29
largestPrimeFactor(600851475143) # => 6857
```

When running these different implementations w/ `benchmark` (also part of the ruby standard library) you can see the vast improvement

```
                           user     system      total        real
JS port                0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.036535)
without memozation     0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.017466)
with memozation        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000199)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is not really how I would solve this if I needed to use this code, but this is how I would write the most similar solution to what you have.

I use two methods to make it easier to use. To output the answer (I think you struggled with that in a different problem), you will need to run:

```
puts largest_prime_factor(600851475143)
```

And here is the code:

```
def largest_prime_factor(input)
  i = 1
  while i < input
    input /= i if (is_prime?(i) && input%i == 0) 
    i += 1
  end
  input
end

def is_prime?(num)
  (2...num).each {|i| num%i == 0 ? false : true}
end
```